# Focus on (scroll to) a DIV element in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a toggle DIV element and I want to focus on (scroll to) it when it opens.

I followed the [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) together with `tabindex="-1"` with no effect.

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            formVisible: false
        }

        this.formRef = React.createRef();

        this.onReply = this.onReply.bind(this);
    }

    onReply(e) {
        this.formRef.current.focus(); // doesn't have any effect

        this.setState({formVisible: true});
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <a onClick={this.onReply} href="#">Reply</a>
            </div>
            <div>
            ....
            </div>

            <div ref={this.formRef} tabindex="-1">
            {this.state.formVisible &&
               <form>
               ...
               </form>
            }
            </div>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

So far I'm using an anchor, but I don't find this solution very elegant...

```
...
<a onClick={this.onReply} href="#form">Reply</a>
...
<a name="form"></a>
{this.state.formVisible &&
...
```

Another problem of the anchor approach is, when there are more dynamically created elements on the page. Then I have to use some kind of ID for the anchor, which is pretty complex:

```
const {id} = this.props.data;
...
<a onClick={this.onReply} href={"#form-" + id}>Reply</a>
...
<a name={"form-" + id}></a>
{this.state.formVisible &&
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your form is rendered only when `formVisible` is `true`, you need to wait until your component is re-rendered before trying to scroll to it. Use `componentDidUpdate` combined with [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView):

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  // `formVisible` went from false -> true, scroll the <form> into view
  if (!prevProps.formVisible && this.props.formVisible) {
    this.formRef.current.scrollIntoView();
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to focus on the DIV element which is rendered independently on the form... `<div ref={this.formRef} tabindex="-1">`. But `scrollIntoView()` is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks!